# what is `vsc-initialized`?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the `vsc-initialized` class that appears on `body` elements and some other elemets I see in DevTools when inspecting pages in Chrome and FireFox?

I have also noticed it in some HTML code pasted in questions and answers around the site, and [a lot of it on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=HTML&q=vsc-initialized&type=Code).

Comment: Any libraries associated?  AngularJS has a similar class that does a bit of the opposite, `ng-cloak`.  Probably just a simple hook to determine some initialization (bootstrap, load, etc) has happened.

Comment: no class - just plain Js.

Comment: i mean no library.

Comment: huh. it seems it appears in firefox, even when there are no scripts. It's also not caused by editing innerhtml or the element's style with JS in chrome. Maby something in the HTML or JS standards?

Comment: No, if it was part of the standard it would be documented. I've never seen it personally. My only guess is it's something an IDE is injecting during a debug session...? No idea.

Comment: it's added by the browser at some point i think - <https://i.imgur.com/oUUpCXl.png> is the raw sresponse, <https://i.imgur.com/bKbBnxZ.png> is what comes up in devtools. inspect this page - the body class is vsc-initialized. `<body class="question-page unified-theme vsc-initialized" style="">` look at the raw response in the network tab or curl. it's not there `<body class="question-page unified-theme">`.

Comment: I just checked and I don't have that class added.  It could also be a browser plugin/extension that a lot of people have...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183979/discussion-between-derpmarine-and-phix).

Answer (score 187, accepted):

After some [in-chat detective work](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183979/discussion-between-derpmarine-and-phix) it's being added by the [Video Speed Controller](https://github.com/igrigorik/videospeed/blob/master/inject.js) browser extension.

Seems a lot of people have that extension installed.

Comment: Nice detective work! I thought vsc means Visual Studio Code. :/

Comment: Yeah I also thought it was Visual Studio Code - what a deceitful coincidence! This is actually causing me issues though as the vsc elements from the plugin are taking up grid spaces in my CSS Grid! This will be a strange one to solve as I don't want people visiting my site getting all these blank grid spaces... It's happening as I have videos inside a grid gallery...

Comment: Wow. A while ago I got hydration errors because of Dark Reader extension, and now this :/ Here's a chrome extension that I now use to turn off all my extension while development, might help others too: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/disable-extensions-tempor/lcfdefmogcogicollfebhgjiiakbjdje

Comment: Browsers now allow you to create multiple profiles, you should use this feature instead and create a new browser profile for development only (and not install extensions in it). also you can have multiple profiles open at the same time. @stuckoverflow